# TypeScript Compilation

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, npm, tsc

Whatever solutions I tried from the net I couldn't succed:

tsc : The term 'tsc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.

I cannot compile .ts files using tsc because there is no tsc even I tried to install numerous times.

I add variable path, installed globally etc. I couldn't see what I missed. Thanks.

Comment: Well _The term 'tsc' is not recognized_ sounds like you don't have installed tsc (TypeScript). Did you install [tsc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript) by a `npm install -g typescript` and re-open terminal?

Comment: Generally in NodeJS projects, your programs are run through scripts in your package.json rather than directly from the command line. For example, you might use `npm run tsc`, which will run `tsc` under the hood. NPM manages all the changes with the PATH variable itself

Comment: You can try [`npx --package=typescript tsc`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npx#examples)